# Taking only a part of a text to an array

Tags: c

If I want to take the text in between two slashes
for example:

```
char str[] = ABCDEFG/HIGKLM/NOPQRS,str[];
While (str[index]!= '\0'){
str1 = TEXT BETWEEN THE SLASHES;
}
```

So first I want to get "ABCDEFG" into a different array, then "HIGKLM" and finally "NOPQRS"

Comment: `strtok` is what your are looking for https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html

Comment: so search `strtok()`

Comment: `strtok()` is not a good solution, since it uses `static` variables which can be a problem when you use more than one thread, call some other functions in the meantime that use their own `strtok()` calls or when you write code that may end up in a library. If you use anything that supports POSIX, `strtok_r()` could be a better solution or write your own function, this should not be that hard.

Comment: Your code is not valid code. What is `ABCDEFG`? Did you mean `"ABCDEFG"`? Or are this variables or macros? Also what is `While`? Did you mean `while`?